# Integrate a Vue Cli project into a Django project? how can i do this?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue Js Client project in which I am making requests from the beginning to my Django server which provides me with texts, image and video paths, these video and image paths are found in the root of my Django project within the Media folder, I need help to integrate my vue project after running the "npm run build" command and it has become static files, to my Django project so that I can use my app on a single port and take it to production, here Below I leave an example of a template in which I am using a video in one of my Vue components, since I think I have to readjust the paths of the videos and images to make them work.

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video ref="videoRef" :src="require(`../../../media/${videoPath}`)" class="video-element" autoplay muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption container">
        <h2 class="RalewayFont multimedia_title" style="color: #F5811C;">{{ videoContent.titulo }}</h2>
        <p class="text-white description_Multimedia RalewayFont ">{{ videoContent.descripcion }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light button_Multimedia RalewayFont" style="border-radius: 50px;" @click="restartVideo">Menú</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, inject } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const data = inject('$data');
    const videoRef = ref(null);

    const playVideo = () => {
      videoRef.value.play();
    };

    const restartVideo = () => {
      videoRef.value.currentTime = 0;
      videoRef.value.play();
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      videoRef.value.addEventListener('ended', restartVideo);
      playVideo(); // Reproducir el video automáticamente al montar el componente
    });


    const videoPath = data.Multimedia_Principal[0].video;
    const videoContent = data.Multimedia_Principal[0];

    return {
      videoRef,
      videoPath,
      videoContent,
      restartVideo
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54pXa.png)